# Koa middleware - generator concurrency testing

Tags: unit-testing, concurrency, generator, middleware, koa

I've hit a bit of an interesting road block in my attempt at writing unit tests for some middleware as I can't seem to come up with a feasible means to fake two concurrent connections for a generator function which is a piece of koa middleware.

I have a constructor function that takes some setup options and returns a generator. This generator has access to some variables via closure which increment per request and decrement when the complete. Here is a subset of the code to give you an idea of what i'm trying to accomplish.

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) {
    let connections = 0;
    let {
        max = 100
        ...
    } = options;

    return function *() {
        connections++

        ...

        if (connections > max) {
            connections--;
            // callback here
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

In simple terms I want to be able to keep track of multiple simultaneous "connections" in which I fire a callback when a max number of requests have been met. However, in my test i get back a single instance of this generator and can only call it once mimicking a single request, thus i can never meet the **connections > max** conditional

```
it("Should trigger callback when max connections reached", () => {
    const gen = middleware({
        max: 1,
        onMax: function (current, max) {
            this.maxReached = true;
        }
    }).call(context);

    gen.next();

    expect(context.maxReached).to.be.true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need a good night sleep to dream your answer. This was simply a matter of calling the same generator with two different contexts that represented two different requests and store a value to tests against on the latter. The counter would still increment because I never returned up the middleware chain (response) in order to decrement. It's more of a fake concurrency.

```
const middleware = limiter({
    max: 1,
    onMax: function (current, max) {
        this.maxReached = true;
    }
});

middleware.call(reqContext).next();
middleware.call(secondReqContext).next();

expect(secondReqContext.maxReached).to.be.true;
```